# How to programmatically create textblock using Segoe MDL2 Assets Font in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I guess this should be easy, but instead of the icon I require, I get a bunch of square boxes.

Originally I was hard coding a menu in xaml:

```
code omitted
<ListBoxItem Name="menuHome" >
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE10F;" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Home" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="15,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
</ListBoxItem>
code omitted
```

I now have to dynamically create this menu so I have the following:

```
ListBoxItem menuHome = new ListBoxItem();
StackPanel menuHomeStackPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
menuHomeStackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe MDL2 Assets"), FontSize = 16, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, Text = "&#xE10F;" });
menuHomeStackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { FontSize = 16, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, Text = "Home", Padding = new Thickness(15, 0, 0, 0) });
menuHome.Content = menuHomeStackPanel;
menuHome.Name = "menuHome";
IconsListBox.Items.Add(menuHome);
```

This almost gives me the same except for the Segoe MDL2 Assets font which can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

Any ideas - probably simple...?

Comment: For VB.net should use text = ChrW("&HE10F")

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Text = "\xE10F"
```

Comment: worked like a charm - thanks. What is the \ doing? - Saying "This is a character and not a string literal" ?

Comment: @Rick `\x` is the prefix used in C# string literals to indicate that the next four characters are a hex character code. It's an exact equivalent of the XML `&#xE10F;` notation.

Comment: Cool thanks - still picking up little titbits like this.

Comment: @EdPlunkett this is not working on UWP, please help.

Comment: @Aasish No. How can I guess what you did wrong? You don’t even say what you’re trying to do, or how you tried to do it, or what went wrong. Ask a real question. Show what you tried and say exactly what went wrong. Maybe someone will help you.

Comment: @EdPlunkett sorry my bad, this is what I have tried ``var btn = new Button() { Content = "\xE10F", Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0) }`` , also tried with other options on your answer but it renders like screenshot on question.

Comment: @Aasish Google “MVCE”. Post a question on Stack Overflow. Mention this answer so you may not be closed as a duplicate. Good luck. I’m not set up for UWP here and have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: @Aasish For reasons which are obvious if you understand my answer, I don’t believe the problem is in the code snippet you showed me: C# string literal escapes aren’t redefined when you’re building for UWP. It’s part of the language.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, thank you for your help, I fixed problem. In my case ``FontFamily`` wast not set, works as expected on setting ``FontFamily`` to button ``var btn = new Button() { Content = "\xE10F", Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0), FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe MDL2 Assets") }`` .

Comment: "\xe734" works, but how would you convert using string interpolation? $"\xe{glyph}" this returns "\u000e789"

Comment: How can it be done in WPF ?

Answer (score -2):

You can try this.

I'm pretty sure it would work:

```
Text = ""
```

Yep, it worked.